# Как осуществить DragnDrop в Eclipse (Java)

Tags: java, android, eclipse, drag-n-drop

Есть объект. Нужно, чтобы при свайпе пальцем в любой области экрана, этот объект двигался влево\вправо соответственно.

Comment: @Максим Мудрый, Согласно правилам форума, вопросы не должны сводиться к решению либо завершению учебных заданий за учащихся. Пожалуйста, уточните, что вы сделали сами и что не получилось.

Answer (score 1):

Определяете touchListener и смотрите начальные и конечные точки, по результатам двигаете вправо или влево.
Вот почти готовое решение http://developer.android.com/training/graphics/opengl/touch.html